# Login do Facebook em aplicações desktop

Tags: java, facebook

Gostaria de saber se existe uma API do Facebook para aplicações desktop, para eu poder integrar na mesma, o login usando a conta do facebook etc. Eu fiz o cadastro e criei minha aplicação no site de desenvolvedores do facebook, aí ele me pediu para escolher a plataforma da mesma, e as disponiveis são Android, iOS e Facebook Canvas (não sei o que é isso). A minha aplicação está sendo desenvolvida em Java SE, existe uma API para esta linguagem?

Comment: Veja esta pergunta no SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883549/how-to-connect-facebook-with-java-desktop-application

Answer (score 2):

Existe o [**Scribe**](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) que serve para tratar esse tipo de autenticação.

No [README](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java#supports-all-major-10a-and-20-oauth-apis-out-of-the-box) do projeto consta suporte ao Facebook e outras redes que utilizam o mesmo tipo de protocolo de autenticação: [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). Talvez você vá estranhar a forma como ele trabalha, nada é automático como quando você autoriza o acesso às suas informações por meio de uma aplicação web:

<kbd>conectar com o Facebook</kbd> **...** <kbd>autorizar</kbd> **...** pronto.

No caso de uma aplicação desktop o fluxo para autenticação é manual. A API retornará uma URL de autorização, o usuário terá que copiar essa URL e abri-la em um navegador de internet — isso você pode fazer na sua aplicação, abrir o navegador padrão direto na página de autorização.

Depois de permitir o acesso, o usuário vai receber um código de autorização que deve ser devolvido para o Scribe continuar o fluxo de autenticação, ou seja, copiar o código lá no navegador e colar em algum campo de entrada na sua aplicação, talvez essa seja a parte chata.

Um [exemplo](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java) para conectar com o Facebook retirado do repositório do projeto:

```
import java.util.*;

import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;

public class FacebookExample {

    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
    private static final Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Altere com sua API Key e API secret:
        String apiKey = "your_app_id";
        String apiSecret = "your_api_secret";

        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                .apiKey(apiKey)
                .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                .callback("http://www.example.com/oauth_callback/")
                .build();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("=== Fluxo de autenticação OAuth pelo Facebook ===");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Buscando a URL de autorização");
        String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);
        System.out.println("URL de autorização obtida.");
        System.out.println("Agora vá e autorize o Scribe nesse link: ");
        System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
        System.out.println("E cole o código de autorização aqui");
        System.out.print(">>");
        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println();


        System.out.println("Negociando o token de requisição para obter o token de acesso...");
        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);
        System.out.println("Token de acesso obtido!");
        System.out.println("(Se estiver curioso, o Token de acesso se parece com isso: " + accessToken + " )");
        System.out.println();


        System.out.println("Agora nós vamos acessar um recurso protegido ...");
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
        System.out.println("Feito! Vamos ver o que encontramos...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(response.getCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("É isso! Vá e crie algo incrível com Scribe! :)");
    }
}
```

Existem [algumas perguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/scribe?show=all&sort=recentlyactive) no StackOverflow<sup>[en]</sup> que tratam do uso dessa biblioteca.